# How can I get a list of positions in array of repeated word in string in php

Tags: php

Lets say I have string something like 
`b<a=2<sub>2</sub> && d>c = 4<sub>2</sub> == 6<sub>3</sub>`
"< sub>" word is repeated 3 times. How can I get all 3 positions into array?

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

```
$find = 'b<a=2<sub>2</sub> && d>c = 4<sub>2</sub> == 6<sub>3</sub>';
function strpos_all($haystack, $needle) {
    $offset = 0;
    $allpos = array();
    while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $offset   = $pos + strlen($needle);
        $allpos[] = $pos;
    }
    return $allpos;
}
print_r(strpos_all($find, "<sub>"));
```